# How can I speed up reading from small spreadsheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a relatively medium size spreadsheet - 212 rows x 56 columns of data.

I have a loop that progressively gets slower and slower the closer my search is to the bottom of my spreadsheet. If can be as quick as 200ms and up to 7000ms to return a response.

How can I accelerate the search such that the time is at least constant or at least accelerated significantly such that it never exceeds 500ms.

Here is how I'm opening the spreadsheet:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data/%s' % filename, read_only=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Service%s' % service)
```

Here is my loop:

```
for i in range(3, sheet.max_row+1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value) == country:
        for x in range(2, sheet.max_column+1):
            if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value):
                abort(404, "Maximum Weight Exceeded for Service Class")

            if weight < float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value):
                return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)

            if weight == float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=x).value):
                return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=x).value)

            if weight < float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=x).value):
                return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=x).value)
```

Edit:

After everyone's suggestions, I've refactored the method. It appears to be much faster however I'm unsure how to access a *specific* row while nested within the for loop. New code below:

```
if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value):
    abort(404, "Maximum Weight Exceeded for Service Class")

minweight = float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value)

for row in sheet.rows:
    if row[0].value == country:
        if weight < minweight:
            return row[1].value

        for cell in row[1:]: # skip first item
            if weight <= float(cell.value):
            # This is wrong. I need to compare weight to cell values in the 2nd row
                return float(cell.value)
```

Edit 2 - now runs ~300ms:

```
if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value):
    abort(404, "Maximum Weight Exceeded for Service Class")

minweight = float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value)

ignore_first_row, weight_list = islice(sheet.rows, 0, 2)

for row in islice(sheet.rows, 2, sheet.max_row):
    if row[0].value == country:
        if weight < minweight:
            return row[1].value # return country's min rate

        for ratecell, weightcell in izip(row, weight_list):
            if weight <= float(weightcell.value):
                return float(ratecell.value)
```

Comment: Looking at what you got there, you can definitely improve on your `if` statements. You are in a `for x in range()` loop, and one of your logic checks doesnt use `x` or `i`  

Specifically, it looks like the `if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value)` could be moved outside the loop?

Comment: Yes good catch and will move it outside of the loop; although would that greatly impact performance?

Comment: Sequentially searching a flat file is obviously going to take longer to find a match near the end of the file compared to a match near the start. That's an inherent property of sequential search.

Even so, 7000ms is spectacularly slow, which makes me suspect you're doing loads of extra disk reads. Rather than arbitrarily micro-optimising, use a profiler such as `cProfile` to measure what is taking so long.

That said, I'd start by iterating the rows using `sheet.iter_rows()` or `sheet.rows` instead of cell lookups.

Comment: `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_column` are properties that are calculated every time they are accessed. Just use `for row in ws.rows` as all rows are guaranteed to be the same length.

Comment: Getting a specific row is easy: `ws.rows` returns a tuple of all the rows so you can slice it. The underlying `ws.iter_rows()` returns an generator so you can use `itertools.islice`. If you need a counter then simply wrap the relevant iterator in `enumerate(iterable, start=1).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following ... not sure how to use slice in this scenario to call on a specific row from within the inner (column) loop ?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do but you seem intent on working against the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generated an xlsx file with 1 sheet containing 57 columns and 200 rows. Each column bar the last contained a randomly generated 100 character string, and the last column was a 6 character arbitrary but non-random sequence to use as a search target.

The following code, using `sheet.rows` is about 7x faster (350ms):

```
for row in sheet.rows:
    if str(row[sheet.max_column-1].value) == needle:
        # needle defined to match only the last row
        print 'found'
        break
```

Than the stripped down equivalent of your code (2400ms):

```
for i in xrange(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=sheet.max_column).value) == needle:
        # needle defined to match only the last row
        print 'found'
        break
```

Note that I have an SSD and a fast processor - YMMV depending on hardware and actual data. You can't really guarantee the search time will be less than a given time unless the data and hardware are essentially constants.

As I said in a comment, you really should learn to use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) or similar to benchmark your code, though.

In my comment I also noted that searching sequentially inherently takes longer to find a match further along in the sequence. To change the time complexity of the search, you would need to change your algorithm, and that means structuring the data differently (i.e. not using a flat file). A binary search is generally much faster than a sequential one but requires sorted data.

Depending on what else you need to do (Do you need to modify the data in the sheet? How often? How large is your data? Does it really have to remain in an Excel sheet?) it might be possible to further improve your search greatly, or not at all.

As CharlieClark pointed out in the comments, `row[-1]` is probably faster than `row[sheet.max_column-1]` (or you could take it outside the loop since your rows are always the same length) and you don't need to cast `cell.value` to a string if you're expecting string data in those cells.

---

Update:
`sheet.rows` is a property that returns a generator, at least in v2.3.5, so no, you can't slice it unless you use `itertools.islice`.

However, you could store the generator returned in a variable, call `.next()` twice to retrieve and store the first two rows, and then iterate the rest of it.

```
row_gen_use_once = sheet.rows
# should really try/except for StopIteration in the next() calls in case there are less than two rows, or else check the row count beforehand
first_row = row_gen_use_once.next()
second_row = row_gen_use_once.next()

for row in row_gen_use_once:
    pass # blah blah do stuff
    # now you can access the second row here :)
```

Or you could use `enumerate` and save the second row from within the loop:

```
first_row = None
second_row = None

for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
    if idx == 0:
        first_row = row
    elif idx == 1:
        second_row = row
    else:
        pass
        # blah blah do stuff
```

That means some extra checks in the loop, but they won't create too much overhead due to branch prediction.

`itertools.islice` version, which is the best solution in my opinion:

```
from itertools import islice
first_row, second_row = islice(sheet.rows, 0, 2)

for row in islice(sheet.rows, 2, sheet.max_row):
    pass # do stuff
```

Unless you are using Python 3, in which case just do:

```
first_row, second_row, *other_rows = sheet.rows

for row in other_rows:
    pass # do stuff
```

Comment: As you note, openpyxl already provides optimised access to rows (and columns) so there is no need to write your own code to do this. It also handles type conversion so `str(cell.value)` is redundant. Rows are evenly sized so calling `ws.max_column` (this is a property that comes with a call) is expensively redundant: `row[-1]` is better. Should boost things a bit.

Comment: @CharlieClark Good points. I used `row[-1]` originally, but switched to `ws.max_column` in my example to stay more directly comparable to the asker's version. The asker should bear in mind that changes like that are good but probably won't make anywhere near as much difference as using `ws.rows` instead of their own iteration.

Comment: I dunno, I suspect calling `ws.max_column` could actually be the limiting the factor, though the nested loops make the code difficult to understand.

Comment: @CharlieClark Just tested your theory about 'ws.max_column' being limiting factor by moving them outside of loop and calling it only once. Still extremely slow ...

Comment: @CharlieClark 1) it made little/no difference switching from `[-1]` in my case, 2) function calls are relatively cheap in Python, and 3) I doubt the implementation is so naive as to recalculate the value every time.

Comment: FWIW it's not the function call that's expensive but the underlying code goes through all cells in a worksheet.

Comment: @CharlieClark link to source? If that's true for read-only workbook instances, that's a terrible implementation.

Comment: No, it's not true for `read-only`, just standard-mode, but it is the optimum for this. But dimensions for those workbooks may not be available, in which case the reader would have to read all the cells.

Comment: @IskarJarak Your suggested updates worked perfectly. I'm now executing at a consistent 300ms or so for worst case - last row, last column. Will update my code in a moment.

Comment: @CharlieClark If it's not true for read-only, it's not relevant here because the asker is explicitly opening the workbook as read-only.

Comment: @K997 Great, glad to hear it.

Comment: Iskar, how `max_column` and `max_row` are obtained does matter because they may well not exist in the file being read. In general, there is no need to rely on them in code like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some of my immediate thoughts:

```
for i in xrange(3, sheet.max_row+1):
    if str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value) == country:

        if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value):
            abort(404, "Maximum Weight Exceeded for Service Class")
        if weight < float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value):
            return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)

        for x in xrange(2, sheet.max_column+1):
            if weight <= float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=x).value):
                return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=x).value)
```

This moves two of your logic checks together (the `<=`) and the other two outside of the loop

Additionally, depending on where you calculate `weight`, this statement should be somewhere else in your code:

```
if weight > float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=sheet.max_column).value):
        abort(404, "Maximum Weight Exceeded for Service Class")
```

It doesn't utilize `i` or `x`, so you don't need to waste time checking it every time the loop hits it

Could you clarify what this block is supposed to do:

```
if weight < float(sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value):
    return float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
```

In your loop, `weight` is not changing. It's a static check that will return from your function utilizing whatever the current value of `i` is. It doesn't make sense given the code you've shown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - you're right, those two checks can be move outside of the column for loop. The weight > float statement can actually be moved outside of the loops entirely.

Comment: With respect to your question - it's basically meant to say, "if the weight is less than the smallest amount, then simply select the smallest amount". This too can also be moved outside of the loops entirely.

Comment: I just made the code changes and while the logic checks out, the loop still runs slowly. The slow down is definitely occurring from the row loop (the first for loop) - not the column loop. Not sure what can be done to speed up going down the spreadsheet?